# In iOS how to check string against regular expression with boolean result

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

In iOS I need to check string against regular expression and if it passes then to return `true` (for example), if not `false`. I understand that I have to use `NSRegularExpression` class, but I can not figure out how.

Comment: Try working through that http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet

Comment: 10x, [Joe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/843150/joe) I will study that article.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here is an example code how to do this in general:

```
- (BOOL)checkString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *const expression = @"^\\d{3}[-]\\d{2}[-]\\d{4}$"; // insert yours
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression * const regExpr = 
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression 
                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                error:&error];

    NSTextCheckingResult * const matchResult = [regExpr firstMatchInString:string
                              options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

   return matchResult ? YES : NO; 
}
```

Comment: Actually I looked in the documentation but I have problem with `NSTextCheckingResult`, 10x for the quick answer.